# why this particular line of code is needed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python from Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way book and I wrote this code:

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."
```

however, I want to know why he used "bear_moved = False" because i runned the program a couple of times and used taunt bear and I always get "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now." Then what's the point of the second "taunt bear" part of the code?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try inputting "taunt bear" twice in a row?

Comment: Because you can't reference variables before assignment

Comment: `not bear_moved` always evaluates to the opposite of that variable. so initially it's `False`, and `not False` means it's `True`. Note that this doesn't change the value of that variable, becasue there's no assignment. and later within that same condition block, you can see that it's assigning `True` to the `bear_moved` variable. Others have already mentioned why you have to declare variables before using them.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the variable `bear_moved` is being read from (checked for being false) in this line:

```
elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
```

Which means it is being referenced. You can't reference a variable before assigning it. Thus, enter `>taunt bear` twice and your program goes to `dead` and the program exits out with the given message.

Try removing the line and you will be presented with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    bear_room()
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\test.py", line 18, in bear_room
    elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bear_moved' referenced before assignment
```

which states what we discussed above. While learning programming, experimentation is the best way to do it.

Comment: I didn't pick up that it would reference a variable before assignment. This is the most correct/accurate answer so far.

Comment: Ahhh okay that makes so much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @BobBunnyIf it answers your question, you may accept it as answer by clicking the check mark beside the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never read the book, but this is what I'm assuming is happening.

```
"The fat bear is in front of another door."
```

So the bear is in it's original position (in front of the door) and has not moved yet as can be seen from `bear_moved = False`

When you taunt the bear, the bear then moves from the door, as can be seen here:

```
 elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
        print "The bear has moved from door. You can go through it now."
        bear_moved = True
```

Since it is no longer in it's original position, the bear has moved so we set `bear_moved = true`.

Now if the user taunts the bear again while `bear_moved = true`, the bear does something else:

```
elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
```

Notice that in the first elif, it says `"taunt bear" and not bear_moved` whereasin the next elif, it says `"taunt bear" and bear_moved`. The first is checking whether the bear hasn't moved, the other is checking whether the bear has moved.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

They are two diffent statments with two diffent paramaters. One of them says if taght bear and bear moved then do something, this will only do something if the bear DID move AND you tuangted him, however the other one will only do something if the the bear DID NOT move AND you tuanghted him. Get it they are two diffent thing because one will go of if he didnt move  and one will go off if he did move.